# Excel formula for "skipping to write" in cell if conditions are not correct

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I got stuck with a problem where I could use some feedback.
I am looking at cell B1 and C1 if either contains a specific value.
If it does I want to write value from D1 (true or false) to A1.

This is the formula I started with and it's used in A1 (I had to simplify with fruits both due to data protection and simplification):
=IF(OR(B1="Apples";C1="Apples");"D1";"")

The problem now is that I want to "skip" a write if it doesn't contain any of the values but it won't work since the IF statement is left empty.
As you can see in the attached picture, I leave an empty space between each "True".

I did find a lot of solutions on how to "skip" empty cells, but that's not what I am after here. Is this even possible with Excel-formulas or do I need to dig into VBA?

Result of my formula:

[image: Result of my formula]

Expecation:

[image: Expecation]

Does it make sense?

Comment: It's possible, but you'd loose the connection to the data completely IMO. Right now it looks like you just want to know the amount of rows in `B:C` that contain "Apples" and spill an equal amount of `TRUE` down in `A:A`. Could this be part of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/670890)?

Comment: I may have missed the point, but if you want the content of column A untouched if "Apples" are absent in column B and C, why not this:

=IF(OR(B1="Apples";C1="Apples");D1;A1) 

Please excuse any errors - not tested; idea is to leave A1 intact if OR logic fails.

Comment: Are you after count of "Apples" in both column? Or are you trying to find out how many unique rows of B:C that at least contain an "Apples" entry?

Comment: Question unclear. You are referring to A1 while A1 is the header! Also, you description of what you want to achieve does not match the screenshot you provided under expectation.

Comment: I see I need to make it more clear. 
The content in D2 will not be just true or false, it will be all kinds of different contents. Basically the idea is:
If cell B2 or C2 contains X, then fill A2 with contents from D2. If cell B2 or C2 does not contain X, then check B3 or C3 for the same condition. So I kind of want to loop through an array and only pick the cells that fulfill the correct conditions. 
=IF(OR(B2="Apples";C2="Apples");D2;A2) would not work since it would leave A1 blank (which is what I don't want). 

Edit: Changed to 2 instead of 1.

Comment: *So I kind of want to loop* then you need VBA I'm afraid. Anyways, and this is just my personal opinion, your first image with  emtpy cells make sense, your second image no

Comment: I was afraid VBA would be possible to solve this. What if fruit type 1 and fruit type 2 was on a different sheet. Would it make more sense? Because that is the true case. I'll see if I can fix this in some other way. Thanks for the inputs everyone.

Comment: Not sure why you want to list the TRUE's when they're not referring to where it's true in any way. Don't you rather want to list the cell addresses of where the condition is TRUE? Or display a count of TRUE's in 1 cell?

Comment: I see it's causing some confusion. I just want to collect the cases where this is true.  Doesn't matter where it's true, just want to collect them without doing the work manually. I am "looking at"/collecting the information from a list on a different sheet.

Answer (score 0):

My manager actually solved this for me if anyone is interested. The use case is a bit weird I can agree on that, but here is solution:
[Formula required to "scatter the TRUE's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WymJ.png)

[Formula to get the first TRUE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItWql.png)

[Formula for the upcoming TRUE's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrUKa.png)